# Optimal algorithm for finding the kernel of a polyhderon

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

The kernel of a polygon $P$ is the set of all points in $P$ from which $P$ is entirely visible. Equivalently, it is the convex region given by the intersection of the half-planes defined by the edges of $P$ (facing into $P$). The definition generalizes for a polyhedron.

It is known that the kernel of a *polygon* can be found in linear time by exploiting the order of the half-planes (see "[An Optimal Algorithm for Finding the Kernel of a Polygon](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=322142&dl=ACM&coll=DL&CFID=1009981318&CFTOKEN=40100406)" by Lee and Preparata).

Is there a linear algorithm for a *polyhedron* as well (or some other result about optimality)?